# Is using leaflet with Mapbox GL JS possible?

Tags: javascript, api, leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm attempting to use leaflet layers on a project using a [mapbox GL JS map](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/). Mapbox offers two different ways to instantiate a map, and all the leaflet examples are using the ['classic' Mapbox API](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/). I've build a whole experience using the GL JS way (seemed to have more robust features and documentation):

```
    map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: videoStyle,
    center: [-73.945360, 40.717533], // starting position
    bearing: 90,
    zoom: mapInitZoom // starting zoom
    });
```

However, now that I need to use leaflet in order to get the distance from the center point, all of the leaflet documentation instantiates maps like this:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

Is there a way I can continue my project using the [Mapbox GL JS API](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) and leaflet combined? Can anyone direct me to an examples or parts of the API documentation where I can read about this?

Oh, and the reason I *think* I need leaflet is because I need to add image layers to my map like this reference diagram image:[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add image to a `mapbox-gl-js` map. Here is an example on how to do this: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/

As you can see in the example, you need to add an [ImageSource](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#ImageSource):

```
map.addSource('overlay', {
   type: 'image',
   url: 'https://www.mapbox.com/images/foo.png',
   coordinates: [
       [-76.54, 39.18],
       [-76.52, 39.18],
       [-76.52, 39.17],
       [-76.54, 39.17]
   ]
});
```

and then a [Raster Layer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layers-raster) based on this source:

```
map.addLayer({
        'id': 'overlay',
        'source': 'overlay',
        'type': 'raster',
        'paint': {'raster-opacity': 0.85}
    });
```

Generally speaking `Leaflet.js` / `mapbox.js` is best suited for raster tile sets, while `mapbox-gl-js` is for vector tile sets.

If you want to use `Leaflet` with a vector tile set, you can have a look at some of the Leaflet plugins that support vector tile sets: https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles#clients

Comment: Thanks @kmandov - so I actually did try that method that you described and 1 of 2 things happens - if it's just an image, it loads, but it makes my browser run so slow it crashes. The map.flyTo() is barely moving. And if I add a video layer, then it also crashes the browser but I get a console warning: logged here on github (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3312)